# How to resolve a list of dynamically created Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, githooks

I am writing a git pre-commit hook and I want to be able to pass it an array of commands to execute, for it to execute them, and if any fail throw an error. Examples of these commands might be to run a test suite or a build.

I am having problems dynamically doing this using the promisified version of Node's child_process exec command.

So far I have a config file with 2 example commands:

**config.js**

```
const config = {
  onPreCommit: ['git --version', 'node -v'],
};

module.exports = config;
```

If I pass in the values manually with this code I get the promise objects fulfilled with the correct values from the commands as I'd expect:

**pre-commit hook**

```
function preCommit() {
  if (config.onPreCommit && config.onPreCommit.length > 0) {
    Promise.allSettled([
      exec(config.onPreCommit[0]),
      exec(config.onPreCommit[1]),
    ]).then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result)));
  }
}

preCommit();
```

However, if I try and do this dynamically like below, this throws an error:

```
function preCommit() {
  if (config.onPreCommit && config.onPreCommit.length > 0) {
    const cmdPromises = config.onPreCommit.map((cmd, i) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmd[i])
          .then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    });

    Promise.allSettled(cmdPromises).then((results) =>
      results.forEach((result) => console.log(result))
    );
  }
}

preCommit();
```

Promises rejected with:

`Error: Command failed: o
  'o' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.`

and

```
Error: Command failed: o
  'o' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: While checking more on this i think this statement is a valid one "The exec function which is executed asynchronously can be used to run shell commands. However, if you want to wait for its result then it is becoming cumbersome: instead of returning a Promise, there is a callback"

Comment: I think the problem might be `exec(cmd[i])` which should be `exec(cmd)`. (the 'o' is possibly 'node'[1])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [comment by mtkopone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802674/how-to-resolve-a-list-of-dynamically-created-promises#comment109316364_61802674), the issue was in my map function.

Fixed by changing `exec(cmd[i])` to `exec(cmd)`

Also updated function so hook works as intended:

```
function preCommit() {
  if (config.onPreCommit && config.onPreCommit.length > 0) {
    // Loop through scripts passed in and return a promise that resolves when they're done
    const cmdPromises = config.onPreCommit.map((cmd) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmd)
          .then((res) => {
            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    });

    // Make sure all scripts been run, fail with error if any promises rejected
    Promise.allSettled(cmdPromises)
      .then((results) =>
        results.forEach((result) => {
          if (result.status === 'rejected') {
            console.log(result.reason);
            process.exit(1);
          }
        })
      )
      .then(() => {
        // If no errors, exit with no errors - commit continues
        process.exit(0);
      });
  }
}

preCommit();
```